# Mocking Enum class in TestNG (Incomprehension of solution)

Tags: java, unit-testing, enums, testng

I need to mock enum class. (Using Mockito and PowerMockito in TestNG)
I was searching for solution, and as a result I found many similar answers:

http://ambracode.com/index/show/285802

[How to mock an enum singleton class using Mockito/Powermock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939023/how-to-mock-an-enum-singleton-class-using-mockito-powermock)

[mocking a singleton class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302179/mocking-a-singleton-class)
[How to mock a method in an ENUM class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21202576/how-to-mock-a-method-in-an-enum-class)

In each provided solution I need to add @PrepareForTest adnotation and mock using powermock.

```
@PrepareForTest( MyEnum.class)
@Test
public void myTest() {

    MyEnumClass mockInstance = PowerMockito.mock(MyEnumClass .class);
    Whitebox.setInternalState(MyEnumClass.class, "INSTANCE", mockInstance);

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyEnumClass.class);

//DoReturn/when and so on...
}
```

But I still do not understand how it suposed to work? If I try it, I will get 
***java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class***

How I can make "*MyEnumClass mockInstance = PowerMockito.mock(MyEnumClass .class);*" if it is enum and final?
I had that problem before i started searching for the result, but every answer looks the same.
What am I missing?

Comment: Could you provide the whole class and stacktrace?

Comment: And as you are using TestNG, you should have a look on https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/TestNG_usage