# Using Mockito: Matching multiple arguments in a private static method?

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I've been trying to use Mockito and PowerMockito to test my code. I have something akin to the following class:

```
public class asdfClass{

    public static String methodToMock(String item, String otheritem){
      return "asdf";
    }

    public static String methodToMock(String item){
      return "asdf";    
    }
}
```

For whatever reason, though, running the following:

```
PowerMockito.spy(asdfClass.class);

PowerMockito.when(asdfClass.methodToMock(Mockito.any())).thenReturn("asdfghj");
```

appears to compile correctly but running

```
PowerMockito.spy(asdfClass.class);

PowerMockito.when(asdfClass.methodToMock(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn("asdfghj");
```

does not and spits out a "'void' type not allowed here" error on the Mockito.any()s.

Does anyone know what to do about this? The only other result I saw on stackoverflow suggested that the reader take a look at the documentation, though I don't think it said anything about multiple arguments in a private static method.

(In the end I'm hoping to mock a void result with a doNothing though I've boiled the issue I'm having down to the fact that all of my void methods take multiple arguments)

EDIT: Never mind, got it: [Is it possible to use partial mocking for private static methods in PowerMock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719919/is-it-possible-to-use-partial-mocking-for-private-static-methods-in-powermock) (Comment 4 on the chosen answer). Curiously this didn't work before but that might've been a typo on my part for all I know)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Is it possible to use partial mocking for private static methods in PowerMock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9719919/is-it-possible-to-use-partial-mocking-for-private-static-methods-in-powermock), PowerMockito.doReturn(mockData).when(DataProvider.class, "readFile", param1, param2, ...) does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You mock void methods, so it can't return anything, so the `thenReturn()` statement should be omitted (for example instead of `when()`, use `doNothing()`).

Comment: Oops; seems that I rushed my code when putting this question up; editing it

Comment: Edited; sorry about that